# I suddenly cannot connect to my server via all service (PuTTY, Ftp, Vesta and Phpmyadmin )

Tags: 14.04, server, ftp, phpmyadmin, putty

I've managed about the VESTACP's large log file because it was too big for my host, the last actions that I(remember) did before everything crashed are

- enabled ufw
- chmod 777 /etc (to update and edit the log rotation in logrotate.conf)
- drop the updated logrotate.conf file to the server.
  for more detail in logrotate.conf : I just add the max sizee + change the 
  rotation from 1 to 5. That's all I edited.

That's all, after that everything is ruined T^T, I cannot connect to my server through anything.

I spent all night to find the solution then found about fail2ban and IP banning issue. It's like my computer was banned from server (not sure). Anyway, I cannot solve the problem LOL. PLEASE HELP.

However, I found that I can access to the terminal trough the vnc browser, so I still can send the command to server.

THANKS FOR ALL SUPPORTING and sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the services you want to use? Try

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow ftp
```

The SSH line would let you login from PuTTy again.

Comment: Thank you for quick replied, I have try it all, but it still not work. Actually, I can access the VESTA loging page only when ufw disabled(cannot access when ufw enabled). sad T^T

Comment: it doesn't connect at all?

Comment: it's does not. For more issue detail, I checked VESTA username and password via terminal, it is matched and correct, but when I try to input it in VESTA panel, it said Invalid username or password.

Comment: Thats strange. Is it a development or a production server? I could help you look into it if you dont mind.

Comment: Ok THX what more informations do you want? TBH I dont really know about development or a production server lol. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You can email me at jerry@lyshnia.com